# How to build specified target only without compiling dependencies on Xcode

Tags: xcode, build, incremental-build

Say, there are two targets on my Xcode project; target A depends on target B. Each time I build target A after modifying source files belonging to it Xcode will build target B too. It will cost considerable time due to some customized shell scripts will be executed for target B.
So my question is how to compile target A only when I modify its sources without building target B?